# Unable to find "Install kubuntu" option

Tags: boot, kubuntu

I am trying to install kubuntu into my Arch Linux laptop. The laptop's hard disk is partitioned to 4 parts. It currently uses systemd as bootloader. I'd like to remove my system and install Kubuntu. On selecting the USB option from the boot potions I get:

In legacy BIOS option: A black screen followed directly by Kubuntu live session loading.

In UEFI option: A choce to load Kubuntu live session, install oem(for manufacturers) and inspect disk.

What do I do to install kubuntu?

Comment: You run a live session and then double-click install Kubuntu?...

Comment: Ahh.. Thanks. Thought there was no such option. It was available in a small bounded square called desk.. ..ider. Didn't notice it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Select the **Kubuntu live session** and, when in the live session the desktop shortcut for "install Kubuntu" can be used to start the installation.

Alternatively the **install OEM** can be used. This is a special installation mode with a temporary user - oem - with full administrative powers. Additional software can be installed and settings can be changed prior to executing the "Prepare for shipping to end user" tool. In the next boot the end user will be taken to the system setup wizard. Additional information with screenshots: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview